# css positioning - right below of a certain div

Tags: html, css

I have created an id of an div element and tried to give these properties:

```
.bu
{
background: #eee; padding: 10px; position:absolute; margin: 0 0 15px 0;width:750px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; 
}
```

And, right after this, i have created another div element with same id but the second div i have added appears at the middle of the first element.

Here is better explanation of the code segment:

```
<div style = "position:absolute; top:50px;">
<div class= "bu">
---something about height 200px
</div>
</div>

<div class="bu">
something
</div>
```

My idea is that the second div should appear right after where the first div ends. I could give the properties "position:absolute;top:250px;" to second div but, the contents of every div will be decided by the users and no certain height. Where am i missing?

Thanks

__ Not master in css __

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same `id` use `class` instead!

Comment: Ok i changed it but still same

Comment: If you want your div's to be aligned relatively then use `position: relative` instead of `position: ablsolute` coz that defined an exact position for them.

Comment: Right, but i did not give position:absolute; top:50px;to the second div so should it appear after the first one?

Comment: If both elements are using same `class` they are bound to inherit same CSS properties, unless they are differenciated by another class or inline css rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is somthing you want

http://jsfiddle.net/mj6Tu/

Answer (score 0):

few position property values are:

**static:** this is default, and it means element will flow normally i.e. left-to-right, and top-to-bottom. elements will positioned themselves **without overlapping**.

**absolute:** it means element will have specific position (left, top, etc..) according to **it's parent** element position. **they might overlap** with other elements, which can be solved using z-index property.

So you might want to create a parent element and give it position absolute...and create 2 inner divs without any position values.

see this code....
http://jsbin.com/welcome/20319/edit